# MySQL nested counts and returning values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched high and low and can't seem to get a way to do what I want. I have a table with some customers, some products and their relationships.

I want to count the amount of returned rows from this part of the query

```
SELECT id
FROM customer
WHERE customer.name = 'SMITH'
OR customer.name = 'JONES'
```

I also want to return the ids that match SMITH and JONES (or other customer names chosen). I want to use the count of the returned rows as a variable (denoted as @var). I only want to return the products, id, and count that match my variable.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way that this can be done in a single SQL query?
2. Is there a way to return the count as well as the values?
3. I don't want to have to throw this into a PHP script or the like.

   ```
   SELECT x.pId, p.productdesc, count(x.dId) as count
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT DISTINCT cId, pId 
       FROM Client 
       WHERE cId IN
       (
           SELECT id
           FROM customer
           WHERE customer.name = 'SMITH'
           OR customer.name = 'JONES'

       )   
   )x 
   JOIN Products p ON x.pId = p.id 
   GROUP BY x.pId 
   HAVING count = @var
   ```

Thanks,

M

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Caution on MySQL...your group by statement is x.pID however p.productdesc is in your select statement.  On any other database, this will return an error, but MySQL will just randomly return the product desc on one of those counted lines.  I assume here that it's an inner join so there is only one value returning for productdesc...so you are likely safe.  Just be careful with MySQL and groupings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of a 'literal' answer to what your asked, as you can use subqueries in the having clause. However, with more information (sample data and expected result) there may be a better way of doing what you want.

```
select x.pid, p.productdesc, count(x.pid) as count
  from (select distinct cl.cid, cl.pid
          from client cl
          join customer cu
            on cl.cid = cu.id
         where cu.name in ('SMITH', 'JONES')) x
  join products p
    on x.pid = p.id
 group by x.pid, p.productdesc
having count(x.pid) = (select count(*)
                         from customer
                        where name in ('SMITH', 'JONES'))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. The `HAVING count(x.pid) = (SELECT count(*) from...` wasn't something I had thought of and gets me out of a pickle. Thanks very much